# presto function to check if array contains subarray

Tags: sql, presto

I have a Presto database with a column array which contains for example:

1. id1,[1,2,3,4]
2. id2,[3,4,5,6]
3. id3,[3,4,7,8]
4. id4,[5,4,3,6]

I need a to search which rows contains the array [3,4,5] in the correct order.
So for instance the result should return only id2 but not id4.

I can use array_intersect in combination with cardinality to find id2,id4 but I don't know how can I verify that id2 or id4 are in the correct order.

The only ugly solution I can think of is to convert the two arrays into a string and then do a string like operation.

Any better ideas?

Following the suggestion below and using AWS Athena:

```
WITH dataset AS (
    (values array[1,2,3,4], 
    array[3,4,5,6], 
    array[3,4,7,8], 
    array[5,4,3,6])
)
SELECT ngrams FROM dataset t(ngrams) where reduce(
    transform(array[3,4,5], a -> array_position(ngrams, a)),
    0, 
    (s, n) -> if( s < 0, -1, if ( n > s, n, -1)),
    s -> s >= 0) ;
```

The error I get is:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 7:44: Unexpected parameters (array(bigint),
>   integer,
>   com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.TypeSignatureProvider@1d8b3792,
>   com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.TypeSignatureProvider@563900c2) for
>   function reduce. Expected: reduce(array(T), S, function(S,T,S),
>   function(S,R)) T, S, R

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the magic for you:

```
select x 
from (values 
    array[1,2,3,4], 
    array[3,4,5,6], 
    array[3,4,7,8], 
    array[5,4,3,6]) t(x)
where reduce(
    transform(array[3,4,5], a -> array_position(x, a)),
    0, 
    (s, n) -> if( s < 0, -1, if ( n > s, n, -1)),
    s -> s >= 0)
```

The above find each element in queried array and returns true if position array is is increasing.
This still have a lot of corner cases to solve (handling duplicates or gaps), but I hope this is something you can start to work with.

See https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html for more details

Comment: Hello I am running the query on Athena but getting an error see above my original question.

Comment: What version of Presto are you using? I was testing that on Starburst Presto Distribution and it was working just fine.

Comment: Interesting Athena uses the Presto 0.172 so is probably different than the Starburst.